# pandas loc attribute behaves as not expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

Could someone please explain why `loc` behaves different from what I expect?

The code is

```
educated_less = df.loc[ ~df['education'].isin(['Masters', 'Bachelors', 'Doctorate'])]
```

It seems that `loc` should return only one column 'education' following the isin condition however
it returns entire df dataframe with all of the columns and `isin` condition is applied.

Comment: Welcome Nikita, we encourage researching your issue before posting an answer. Please read pandas' user guide section on [indexing with isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin), notice how `.loc` can select both row and column indexes as in `.loc[rows, columns]`, you are skipping the column parameter with `.loc[rows]` then all columns will be returned by default

Answer (score 0):

Because [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) indexing has two parts:

```
df.loc[left_part, right_part]

left_part <- where you define by which index to filter
right_part <- where you define which columns you want to keep
```

you are missing the right_part. So, you can do:

```
educated_less = df.loc[ ~df['education'].isin(['Masters', 'Bachelors', 'Doctorate']), ['education']]
```